# Insert XElements after a specific node

Tags: c#, xml, linq

```
  <user Id="4/30/2015 10:16:52 AM">
    <city>Bathinda</city>
    <city>Moga</city>
    <city>Patiala</city>
    <city>Amritsar</city>
    <city>Faridkot</city>
  </user>
```

I want to make an entry in under user node having Id attribute value for this purpose I've used the code following:->

```
 xmlDocument.Elements("user")
            .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Id") == usrCookieId)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .AddAfterSelf(
                 new XElement("adults", drpAdult1.SelectedIndex),
                 new XElement("kids", Convert.ToInt32(drpKids.SelectedIndex)),
                 new XElement("infants", Convert.ToInt32(drpInfants.SelectedIndex)),
                 new XElement("startingDate", datePicker.Value),
                 new XElement("startingCity", drpStartingCity.SelectedValue ));
```

But the Error is Object refrence is not set to an instance of an object.
How can i correct my code above.
Thanks!

Comment: Well maybe you haven't *got* any users matching the input? It would be better to use `First()` here rather than `FirstOrDefault()` as if there aren't any matching elements you *will* get a `NullReferenceException`, which is less clear than `First()` going bang saying there are no matches.

Comment: A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would help us to help you though...

Comment: You can replace the `Where` with the `FirstOrDefault` since `Single`, `SingleOrDefault`, `First` and `FirstOrDefault` are `Where's` that quit when appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting Object Reference Exception because no User Id must be matching the value present in `usrCookieId`. You need to check for nulls to avoid this exception by first fetching the element and adding it after confirming if that user node is present:-

```
XElement userNode = xdoc.Descendants("user")
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => (string)x.Attribute("Id") == usrCookieId);
```

This will return the first matching XElement or null in case no such user node is found so you can simply check this condition and add accordingly:-

```
if (userNode != null)
{
       userNode.AddAfterSelf(new XElement("adults", "3"),
                             new XElement("kids", 2),
                             new XElement("infants", 5),
                             new XElement("startingDate", "23/01.2015"),
                             new XElement("startingCity", "Delhi"));
}
```

Also, Please note since you are intending to add this new node beneath `user` you need to have a root node because currently `user` is acting as root node and by adding this new nodes you will make you XML not well formed and it will throw a run time exception So better have a Root node like this:-

```
 <Users>
  <user Id="1">
    <city>Bathinda</city>
    <city>Moga</city>
    <city>Patiala</city>
    <city>Amritsar</city>
    <city>Faridkot</city>
  </user>
</Users>
```

Comment: I didn't mention But there is <Users> same as u specified But thanks for this. and the book u referred is really good Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're not finding a match, so either `usrCookieID` doesn't isn't equal to any Id or, maybe more likely, `User` isn't the root of your XML. If it isn't, perhaps `Descendants` would be more appropriate here - this finds any `User` element in the document.

`First` (or `Single` if Id is unique) would be more appropriate than `FirstOrDefault`, as a better exception would be thrown.  This will throw an exception explaining that no element was found rather than an unhelpful `NullReferenceException`.

To add a child element to your result, you need to use `Add`.  `AddAfterSelf` will add a sibling element.

So, something like:

```
var user = xmlDocument.Descendants("user")
    .Where(x => (string)x.Attribute("Id") == usrCookieID)
    .Single();

user.Add(new XElement(...));
```